# How to Separate data inside single cell in multiple cell in excel or R

Tags: r, excel-formula

Status update info

```
"Placed | 2018-06-23 08:46:46 Acknowledged | 2018-06-23 08:53:03 Dispatched | 2018-06-23 09:02:54 Completed | 2018-06-23 09:03:12"
"Placed | 2018-06-23 09:03:28 Acknowledged | 2018-06-23 09:03:43 Dispatched | 2018-06-23 09:06:31 Completed | 2018-06-23 09:06:46"
```

I want above data indifferent column:
One column should have 
placed/acknowledged/dispatch/complete and other should have date and time.

How can we do this in Excel and R?

Answer (score 0):

In R

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(A = gsub("Placed\\s+\\||Acknowledged|Dispatched|Completed","",A)) %>% 
       separate(A,c('Placed',"Acknowledged","Dispatched","Completed"),'\\|') %>% 
       mutate_all(funs(trimws(., which = 'both')))

         Placed        Acknowledged          Dispatched           Completed
1 2018-06-23 08:46:46 2018-06-23 08:53:03 2018-06-23 09:02:54 2018-06-23 09:03:12
2 2018-06-23 09:03:28 2018-06-23 09:03:43 2018-06-23 09:06:31 2018-06-23 09:06:46
```

Data

```
df <- read.table(text="
                     A
                    'Placed | 2018-06-23 08:46:46 Acknowledged | 2018-06-23 08:53:03 Dispatched | 2018-06-23 09:02:54 Completed | 2018-06-23 09:03:12'
                    'Placed | 2018-06-23 09:03:28 Acknowledged | 2018-06-23 09:03:43 Dispatched | 2018-06-23 09:06:31 Completed | 2018-06-23 09:06:46'
                     ",header=T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Comment: In R when i am using getting this error

Error in UseMethod("mutate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'mutate_' applied to an object of class "function"

Comment: it works for me. Copy past `df` and starting in a new Rstudio session and load libraries